# Jackson - couldn't write json - infinite recurison

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.3 and I am getting Jackon infinite recursion error.

**Class A**

```
public class A{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    //option2: @JsonManagedReference
    private List<B> listMembers;

    public List<B> getListMembers(){
        return this.listMembers;
    }

    public void setListMembers(List<B> listMembers){
        this.listMembers = listMembers;
    }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B{

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    // Option1: @JsonIgnore
    // Option2: @JsonBackReference
    private A parent;

    public A getParent(){
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(A parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

I have tried following options

1st option is in class `B` on property `parent` put `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

2nd option is in class `A` on property `listMembers` put `@JsonManagedReference` and in class `B` on property `parent` put `@JsonBackReference`.

I am still getting this problems.

This jar files I am using are

- jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
- jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar

Kindly help.

Comment: Could you please post the stack traces in the option 1 and 2?

Comment: @GregorRaýman: for option 1    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet processRequest            Could not complete request
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.priyank.app.domain.B["parent"]->com.priyank.app.domain.A["listMembers"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.priyank.app.domain.B["parent"]->com.priyank.app.domain.A["listMembers"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-and so on rest is 90k characters but repeats the same

Comment: @GregorRaýman: for option2 also it is same :(

Comment: this is very strange. are the classes really recompiled? are the annotations on the classpath?